# Direct link building typo3: with support for utf-8?

Tags: utf-8, typo3, urlencode, typo3-6.1.x

I decided to put my address significant link, I'm using typo3 
Already Address: http://www.ssu.ac.ir/cms/index.php?id=47 
Target address: http://www.ssu.ac.ir/cms/دامشگاه_علوم_پزشکی_یزد

Utf-8 support is important for me because I got the address of the Persian see

How do I implement RealURL with persian content?

Comment: Where is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this by myself, but it might be the sollution for you.
Use the ***enableAllUnicodeLetters*** setting in your RealURL configuration.
You will have to activate the manual configuration to be able to do this.

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'] = array(

  'init' => Array(
    'enableAllUnicodeLetters' => true
    [...]
  )

);
```